# Combine Int and String Arrays at the same index

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I wanna Combine these two arrays at specific index so I get the output like: `178 Pete.` Because they have the same index of [2] ?

```
int[] numbers =
{
     155,192, 178,192
};

string[] names =
{
    "Sam", "Nick", "Pete", "Doug"
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seems a hard problem. Have you tried _anything_ to solve it? For example; iterating both arrays at the same time and concatenate same indexed items and add it to new `string[]` or `List<string>`?

Comment: Hard for me at the moment. :( I've tried to do like a loop and also set them equal to each other but it wont just work

Comment: It would be better to see your _won't worked_ code as well. Then we can figure out when you stuck and how we can help you to solve it.

Comment: why not create a complex type with a property for number and name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this so hard?

```
var r = numbers.Select((x, i) => x + " " + names[i]);
```

This uses the overload for `Select` that expects a `Func<T, int>` to enable indexed access also.

If you need only the entries at a specified index you may simply use this:

```
var result = numbers[myIndex] + " " + names[myIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String thirdNumberName = null;
if(numbers.Length >= 3 && names.Length >= 3)
{
    thirdNumberName = string.Format("{0} {1}", numbers[2], names[2]);
}
```

But why do you store two related informations in two separate collections at all? I would create a class `User` with at least two properties(`Number`,`Name`). Then you can use a `User[]` or `List<User>`.